# print location of match in new column of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

What I want to do is search over a set of columns and return a new column with 
1. the string inside the column as well as the name of the column that it came from

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A1.1234567_10", "A1.1234567_20"), 
                 var1 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var2 = c("NORMAL", "SUSPECTED"), 
                 var3 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var4 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var5 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var6 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                 var7 = c("NORMAL", "ABNORMAL"), 
                 var8 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL")), 
            .Names = c("ID", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8"), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

           ID   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6     var7   var8
A1.1234567_10  NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL   NORMAL NORMAL
A1.1234567_20 NORMAL SUSPECTED NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL
```

I want to to eventually look like this

```
           ID   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6     var7   var8  abnormal_summary
A1.1234567_10 NORMAL NORMAL    NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL   NORMAL NORMAL NA
A1.1234567_20 NORMAL SUSPECTED NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL suspected_var2 ABNORMAL_var7
```

I know that I can index them myself, but the person that is eventually going to be looking at it will need to visualize it in each row.

Comment: are you looking to return all columns that are not 'NORMAL' or just those that are 'SUSPECTED' or 'ABNORMAL'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply` function is going to be the workhorse that loops through each row. Use a custom function on each row to compile a string vector of 'bad' values and their corresponding column name index. Combine the bad value and the column name before concatenating all the bad value-column combinations found on the row. Lastly, the row should be returned as a vector that can be added to the original dataframe.

```
#This example uses the dataframe, `df` you defined in your question. 
#
# this function works on one row at a time and can accept one or more
# accepted values as a character vector.  
library(magrittr)

build_nonnorm_str <- function(row, col_names, norm_value) {
  # get the index of any bad values, excluding the column named "ID"
  bad_col_indx <- which(!row %in% norm_value &
                    !names(row) == "ID")

  # appropriately assign NA to rows with no bad values,
  # otherwise put together the string to be appended to
  # the new dataframe
  if (length(bad_col_indx > 0)) {
    abnorm_str <- paste0(row[bad_col_indx], 
                         "_",
                         col_names[bad_col_indx], 
                         sep = " ") %>%
      paste0(collapse = "") %>%
      trimws()
  } else {
    abnorm_str <- NA
  }

  return(abnorm_str)
}

# Use the apply function to send the function one rows worth of data
# and append it to the new column
df$abnormal_summary <- apply(df,
                             1,
                             build_nonnorm_str,
                             col_names = names(df),
                             norm_value = "NORMAL")
```

Use the logic in the which statement to modify whether you want to exclude all values that are not "NORMAL" or only include those values that are "ABNORMAL" or "SUSPECTED".

Comment: this worked really well. I think i can also pick the columns that this works on by changing `bad_col_index` and changing some of the parameters based instead `bad_col_indx <- which(!row %in% norm_value & grepl("var", row))` because in my actual df there are many more rows besides ID. Thanks again this is awesome

Comment: @Randy you're welcome, thanks for catching the typo in the function call